# Is it possible for javascript file to only affect specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use 2 different open source plugins for my website, a gallery and a calendar, both uses JQuery to work.

But when i put both of their javascript together in my website, it clashes and only one will be able to appear.

Is there any ways to specific if that javascript file just works for one DIV only? Or any work around to have both in my website.

Comment: Without more informations we can't tell you an answer; give more infos and a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: Can you post the script names and at least the code in your page to call/use the script?

Comment: How do you use those plugins?

Comment: What are these `plugins` for? Are they jQuery plugins, or just scripts you've found? If the latter, they maybe using global variables with the same name, in which case you'll need to change the variable names, or use ifferent scripts.

Comment: Some **code** would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any ways to specific if that javascript file just works for one DIV only?

No, there is a single execution environment for a given HTML document. The only way to sandbox JavaScript is to put it in an iframe (even then, there are APIs that allow other documents to be affected)

> Or any work around to have both in my website.

Edit the source of the respective scripts to change which elements they affect and to make them use the same version of jQuery and any other libraries they might depend on.

Comment: i guess i'll try changing the names. thanks!